# Government Registered Companies Websites API

Tags: api, government, companies

Can any buddy help me out to find the API of Government website of Registered Companies. please guide me easy way to find API FOR **REGISTERED GOVERNMENT COMPANIES**

Comment: Welcome to OpenData SE. Can you be more specific on your question? Please mention which location/country you are looking for

Comment: I need for atleast 50 countries .Plz help.

Comment: I think in my opinion you can't find all countries associated dataset in one place. Maybe you need to club everything from different places.

Comment: i have searched  alot on different websites but hardly find a few, if you please tell me any website or somewhere i can find.If not API then at least Open Data for government registered companies websites.